# Android navigation drawer - update fragment manually

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

To give you a bit of background—I’m an iOS developer, and I started experimenting with porting one of my apps to Android. Everything was going well until I came across an issue that had me climbing the walls for the past couple of days.

My app is using the Navigation Drawer template and it’s working fine. I can switch between fragments quite easily by tapping the required navigation item. The problem however is when I try to switch the content from within an existing fragment. In other words, I have a button on one of my fragments and when clicked, I want it to replace the content with another fragment. I’ve managed to accomplish this using the following code:

```
Fragment profileFragment        = ProfileFragment.newInstance(1);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.replace(R.id.container, profileFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

While this code is switching to the desired fragment, the action bar title and the selected navigation drawer item still reflect the previous fragment. I’ve try to update the action bar and select the item manually but I had no luck! I can’t find any references online on how to update the navigation drawer content from within a fragment.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity().setActionBarTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.action_bar_title));
```